# How do I incorporate daylight savings time into an R date-time variable?

Tags: r, datetime, dst

There are a number of similar questions. One suggested using  date('I', strtotime($date)) to identify dates where daylight savings time starts or ends. Then I guess I would use an if-then test to find 2AM start time. I could do this, but is there a simpler solution?
What I have is weather data from a system that does not recognize daylight savings time. To integrate those data with a system that does use daylight savings time I need to convert one system to the other. Is there a package in R to do this?

I converted Date to New_Date by hand in Excel. Not the ideal solution if one has much data.

[image: Convert Date to New_Date]

Comment: Have you checked out `lubridate`, which can handle daylight savings?

Comment: You need to provide an example of datetimes from the "system that does not recognize DST" and what you want these converted to for the "system that does use DST".